# Trouble with RPI Pico and Waveshare SIM868 Module

Tags: pi-pico, gsm

I need some help with SIM868 GSM/GPRS/GNSS Module for Raspberry Pi Pico. A few months ago I bought SIM868 module and RPI Pico, and it works just fine together.

But recently I bought another pair of RPI Pico and SIM868, and now when I connect them together using a female header, Pico just shuts down and disappears from Windows Device Manager. When I unplug Pico from SIM868, it turns on, the led starts blinking and it is visible again on Windows Devices. Standalone Pico works great with Micropython.

The question is **What am I doing wrong?** Maybe somebody has dealt with a problem like that.

P.S. I can do some voltage measurements and/or oscilloscope screenshots if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think something happened to your SIM868. Since you have used the module earlier, I can be sure that you are not making any mistake with the power supply. Try to check the SIM868 separately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).